# after back button, portlet does not go in to processaction

Tags: java, jsp, portlet, websphere-portal

I have a portlet which involves displaying several JSP pages.

In first JSP `page A`, when I click the Submit button on `Page A` the `processAction()` method takes action and a JSP `page B` appears.

Now if I use Web Browser's **Back button** to `page A` and click the Submit button again, the
JSP `page B` appears but I noticed the `processAction()` didn't take any action. (Usually clicking Submit button in a JSP page can result in the `processAction()` to take action).

Can anyone help for this problem? In my Porlet, it MUST go to the process action but it doesn't after back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior. Portal has "`Multiple Action URL Protection` " enabled by default. When a page loads, an action link is created and that link contains an `action ID`. The same action ID cannot be used again in the same session. So when you click on Back Button, if the page is loaded from the history cache, your Form contains the same action link which was used before. So portal simple reloads the page, rather than calling the `processAction()`.
You can disable this by adding the following configuration for your portlet in `portlet.xml` file.

```
<init-param>
   <name>wps.multiple.action.execution</name>
   <value>true</value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I spent a lot of hours for this.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it sounds as if your form response may be cached.  What is the method attribute on your `<form>` ? Forms submitted via `GET` (or no `method` attribute at all) are allowed to be cached; in which case neither the server nor your portlet's `processAction(...)` will be invoked - the browser will re-render the previous response from cache.

If you post some code there may be more offers to help...