# Spring Portlets - Browser Back button is not working

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

On click of browser back, the control is not going anywhere

As suggested in this link 
[after back button, portlet does not go in to processaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456076/after-back-button-portlet-does-not-go-in-to-processaction)

have added wps.multiple.action.execution=true in Portlet.xml, still url is getting cached & not issuing new url. I am using IBM Portal server 6.1 with JSR 168 speciafications.

My Portlet.xml looks below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_1_0.xsd" version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_1_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_1_0.xsd" id="com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.c82f6e6464">
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>BrowserBackPortle</portlet-name>
    <display-name xml:lang="en">BrowserBackPortle</display-name>
    <display-name>BrowserBackPortle</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <name>wps.multiple.action.execution</name>
       <value>true</value>
    </init-param>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    <resource-bundle>com.ibm.browserbackportle.nl.BrowserBackPortlePortletResource</resource-bundle>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>BrowserBackPortle</title>
        <short-title>BrowserBackPortle</short-title>
        <keywords>BrowserBackPortle</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
</portlet>
```

I am trying to invoke a Spring interceptor on click of browser back to intercept the request. Control goes no where, it is not hitting interceptor. My Spring interceptor is below:

```
public class RxFlowInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


@Override
public boolean preHandleRender(final RenderRequest request, final RenderResponse response,
        final Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    System.out.println("---------------PREHANDLERENDER-----------------");

    return super.preHandleRender(request, response, handler);
}
```

}